# Wordpress two loop exclude post

Tags: wordpress

I am using two loop query:

```
<?php
                // show all coupons marked Top Coupon

                query_posts(array(
                        'post_type' => APP_POST_TYPE, 
                        'post_status' => 'publish',
                        'meta_key' => 'clpr_topcoupon',
                        'meta_value'=> 1,
                        APP_TAX_STORE => $term->slug, 
                        'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1, 
                        'posts_per_page' => 1
                ));
                ?>  

                <?php get_template_part( 'loop3', 'coupon' ); ?>    

                <?php

                    query_posts( array(
                        'post_type' => APP_POST_TYPE,
                        'post_status' => 'publish',
                        APP_TAX_STORE => $term->slug,
                        'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
                        'posts_per_page' => -1,
                        'meta_query' => array(
                        'relation' => 'OR',
                            array(
                            'key'     => 'clpr_excoupon',
                            'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
                            ),
                            array(
                            'key'     => 'clpr_excoupon',
                            'compare' => '!=',
                            'value'   => '1'
                            ),
                        ),
                    ) );
                ?>

            <?php get_template_part( 'loop1', 'coupon' ); ?>
```

Now I don't want to show the first post from the first loop in the second loop. I tried `get_the_ID();` however if this one is not having the `'meta_key' => 'clpr_topcoupon'` one post is missing. How do I get the `get_the_ID();` from first post but only if it has the `'meta_key' => 'clpr_topcoupon'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wordpress docs suggest that you should avoid using [query_posts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/) whenever possible stating:

> Note: This function will completely override the main query and isn’t intended for use by plugins or themes. Its overly-simplistic approach to modifying the main query can be problematic and should be avoided wherever possible.

Instead we can use [WP_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) . We'll use the first loop to store the post id and check it during the second loop. Maybe something like this:

```
<?php 
//set parameters for First query
$args = array('post_type' => APP_POST_TYPE, 
                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                    'meta_key' => 'clpr_topcoupon',
                    'meta_value'=> 1,
                    APP_TAX_STORE => $term->slug, 
                    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1, 
                    'posts_per_page' => 1 ); 
$first_query = new WP_Query($args); // create query
$post_id = 0;
//initialize loop for custom query like this
if ($first_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ($first_query->have_posts() ) {
        $first_query->the_post();
        $post_id = $post->ID; //store post ID outside of loop
        get_template_part( 'loop3', 'coupon' ); 
    } 
} 
wp_reset_postdata();
//setup second query
$args = array( //excludes post from query by ID See Bill erikson for complete list of WP_Query() arguments
                    'post__not_in' => array($post_id), 
                    'post_type' => APP_POST_TYPE,
                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                   
                    APP_TAX_STORE => $term->slug,
                    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
                    'posts_per_page' => -1,
                    'meta_query' => array(
                        'relation' => 'OR',
                            array(
                                 'key'     => 'clpr_excoupon',
                                 'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
                             ),
                             array(
                                 'key'     => 'clpr_excoupon',
                                 'compare' => '!=',
                                 'value'   => '1'
                            )
                    )
              );
$second_query = new WP_Query($args);
if ($second_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ($second_query->have_posts() {
        $second_query->the_post();
        get_template_part( 'loop1', 'coupon' );
   }
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Hopefully, this code is able to assist you. As you can see, WP_Query accepts an argument 'post__not_in' that takes an array of page id's and excludes them from the query. We retrieved the id from the first query and referenced it in the argument of the second query. I also included [`wp_reset_postdata`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata) which is worth taking a look at if you're running multiple queries.

Good luck with your project!

Comment: You're setting `$post_id` on each loop. Since OP is only looking to exclude the first ID in `$first_query` from `$second_query`, it would be simpler to just access that post ID directly from the `WP_Query` data when setting `$post_id`

Comment: Tank you, my problem is that query_post is somehow deep connected within my theme. I tried to use WP_Query on several attempt but always getting just a blank page with only the header showing. Same if I use your code. I am somehow lost.

Comment: its working @chris rock however if the post in the first query is empty than the first post of the second query will not show.

Comment: hey my bad joloshop. I haven't taken the time to run the code but its clear that i was missing a comma in the first loop. It looks like you've discovered that yourself. We can make a few modifications to the code to check if the the first query returns any results. We basically create a var equal to 0 and equal to 1 if the first query returns any results. In the second query, we can add the 'post__not_in' parameter iff the variable is equal to 1. relevant changes can be found on this https://pastebin.com/SLChETKs

Comment: Hello Chris, thanks again. Its just not working. I looks like I have the problem that within my theme `query_posts` is so deep implemented that I am unable to change to `WP_Query`

Comment: @ChrisRock now its working, there was just a `endwhile;`missing in front of each `wp_reset_postdata();`

Comment: O that's weird, cause I'm using the curly brackets for the while loops.. Anyway, are you all good now?

Comment: looks like and probably my fault I needed a `else` statement for the loop.

Comment: That’s great to hear! Can you mark my answer as the solution?